# How to retrive data using angular js and which stored json format in MYSQL coloumn

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json

I have JSON data stored in MySQL column like this, column name is payments_json_details

```
[{"amount":"1000","mop":"Cash","paymentdate":"2017-12-04 16:25","remarks":"testt1"},{"amount":"2500","mop":"Cheque","paymentdate":"2017-12-05","remarks":"testt2"}]
```

When we use this angular js for display purpose, iam getting data like above as it is., but i want to retrieve each values like amount, mop etc

```
{{pdata.deliveryinfo[index].payments_json_details}}

<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in pdata.deliveryinfo[index].payments_json_details">
        {{value}}
</span>
```

Iam tried this way, but there is no output, can anyone help?

```
JSON format like this

    {
        "jobcard_id": "33",
        "jobcard_sno": "8",
        "user_id": "140",
        "address_id": "22",
        "delivery_address_id": "22",
        "orderdetails": [{
            "id": "71",
            "jobcard_id": "33",
            "product_id": "462",
            "product_quantity": "2",
            "product_price": "324.00"
        }],
        "deliverydetails": [{
            "id": "4",
            "type": "Delivery Agent"
        }, {
            "id": "5",
            "type": "Delivery Agent"
        }],
        "deliveryinfo": [{
            "delivery_id": "7",
            "order_id": "33",
            "product_ids": "462",
            "payment_collected": "Partial",
            "payments_json_details": "[{\"amount\":\"1000\",\"mop\":\"Cash\",\"paymentdate\":\"2017-12-04 16:25\",\"remarks\":\"testt1\"},{\"amount\":\"2500\",\"mop\":\"Cheque\",\"paymentdate\":\"2017-12-05\",\"remarks\":\"testt2\"}]",
            "totaltime": "39:17:00"
        },{
            "delivery_id": "7",
            "order_id": "35",
            "product_ids": "485",
            "payment_collected": "Partial",
            "payments_json_details": "[{\"amount\":\"5000\",\"mop\":\"Cash\",\"paymentdate\":\"2017-12-04 16:25\",\"remarks\":\"testt1\"},{\"amount\":\"7000\",\"mop\":\"Cheque\",\"paymentdate\":\"2017-12-05\",\"remarks\":\"testt2\"}]",
            "totaltime": "39:17:00"
}],
        "$$hashKey": "testt"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering `pdata.deliveryinfo` is an array containing JSON objects. If its `pdata.deliveryinfo[index].payments_json_details` then use it in `ng-repeat`.

```
<span ng-repeat="data in pdata.deliveryinfo>
   Amount: {{data.amount}}, MOP : {{data.mop}}, Payment Date : {{data.paymentdate}}, Remarks : {{data.remarks}}
</span>
```

Comment: its not working, when i use this only iam getting data pdata.deliveryinfo[index].payments_json_details, but i want to display individual.

Comment: display individual? Do you want to achieve something different in UI?

Comment: i mean {{data.amount}} like this only in ng-repeat, but its not show anything

Comment: ok!! could you post you whole JSON structure, like what are you getting inside `pdata`.

Comment: `payments_json_details` is stringified are you parsing it before using it in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: No, i thought it is not required. where should i put?

Comment: you need to parse before using it in ng-repeat, use `$scope.array = JSON.parse(pdata.deliveryinfo[index].payments_json_details)`, then use array in ng-repeat

Comment: should i put it in ng-init or where?

Comment: put it inside the controller, that would be best practice, you have to manage this according to the amount of data you are receiving from the backend. either loop through whole array if you are receiving more `payments_json_details` or just put it where its required